# Information Criteria and Sample size

Tags: self-study, stationarity, aic, information-criteria

In the estimation of the univariate time series model, we need to determine the correct order. For the general ARMA (p,q) model, we can determine the true order by information criteria

$$AIC(p,q) = ln(\frac{\sum u_t^2}{T-p-q}) +\frac{2p+2q}{T-p-q}$$

$$SIC(p,q) = ln(\frac{\sum u_t^2}{T-p-q}) +\frac{ln(T-p-q)(p+q)}{T-p-q}$$

we know that SIC is used in the large samples while AIC is used in small samples.

However, a bad statistician use AIC for his large sample size in order to ensure the series is stationary. Is it possible that he get the stationary result? How? and what is the negative sides of using AIC in large samples?

---

I guess, in large samples, AIC will overestimate p. So, he gets large p. And then, I guess I should the formula of A. Dickey Fuller (ADF) test or other unit test formula... But I 'm stack at that point.

Also, MA(q) is always stationary. But. AR(p) is  $y_t =\alpha + \phi_1 y_{t-1} + ... + \phi_p y_{t-p} + e_t$
When we re-write it, $Q(L)y_t = \alpha +e_t$ where $Q(L) = (1- \phi_1L- ...-\phi_pL^p) = (1-h_1L)(1-h_2L)...(1-h_pL)$. So the AR(p) process is stationary when $|h_i|<1$ for all i=1,...,p.

Comment: Regarding the first element of AIC and BIC, I think you should take the denominator $T-p-q$ out of the logarithm of the sum of squared residuals. AIC and BIC are usually defined without this denominator at all, but if you put it in, you have to treat both the log-likelihood  term and the penalty term equally (divide them by the same denominator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The justification of both AIC and BIC is asymptotic. AIC is asymptotically efficient while BIC is consistent (which also an asymptotic notion) in model selection, where each property holds under a respective set of assumptions. It is not correct that AIC is better suited for small samples while BIC is suited for large samples.

Lag order selection by AIC or BIC does not have much to do with stationarity of the resulting model. For any model order, the model is fit in either restricted or unrestricted way. If fitting is restricted so that the roots lie in a stationary region, you will get a stationary solution. If fitting is not restricted this way, you may get a nonstationary solution. Whether you use AIC or BIC to select among the candidate models of different lag orders does will not have an effect on the stationarity of the solution.

Comment: @1190, I do not see how it should.

Comment: Can you explain this part more clearly and a bit detail? How can I show restricted or unrestricted model are not affected by the larger order p? "For any model order, the model is fit in either restricted or unrestricted way. If fitting is restricted so that the roots lie in a stationary region, you will get a stationary solution. If fitting is not restricted this way, you may get a nonstationary solution."

Comment: by the way, many thanks for your answer.

Comment: @1190, you are welcome! If there was a mechanism for how model selection afects stationarity, I would explain it. However, there is no such mechanism, so there is no corresponding explanation. If the series is nonstationary, an unrestricted fit of ARMA model will pick the nonstationarity up and yield a nonstationary model. The lag order does not matter much in that respect, as a model of any order (as long as the AR order is 1 or greater) would pick it up.

Comment: okay, there is no specific model that I have. This is a general solution. Just, initially, there is no stationary process. But, in order to get stationary result, AIC is used for large sample. Thank you so much.